# Spring Boot pom - how to inherit profiles and properties from aggregator pom?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, properties, integration-testing

### Objectives

I'm adding integration tests to a Maven build. I want to achieve the following goals:

- Only unit tests are run by default.
- It must be possible to run only integration tests.

### Current state

The task becomes more complicated because this is an existing application with a confusing structure (hierarchy) of maven modules. I'll try to explain.

So I have an aggregator pom (super pom) that looks like

```xml
<groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>app-name</artifactId>
<modules>
    <module>SpringBootApp1</module>
    <module>SpringBootApp2</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Only unit tests are run when the development profile is active -->
            <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
            <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Test</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- Only integration tests are run when the test profile is active -->
            <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
            <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and a few module poms that do not inherit from super pom (they inherit from `spring-boot-starter-parent`) and look like

```xml
<groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-app</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Spring Boot app</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<build>
    <finalName>SpringBootApp1</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <executions>
                <!--  Invokes both the integration-test and the verify goals of the Failsafe Maven plugin -->
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you see I define `skip.integration.tests` and `skip.unit.tests` properties in the aggregator pom (property values are different for different profiles) and try to use them in module poms.

### Problem

When I execute `mvn clean test -P Test` or `mvn clean verify -P Test` to run tests I see that properties are not applied (e.g. unit tests are executed although `skip.unit.tests` is `true`).

I could declare aggregator pom as parent of module pom and maybe it would solve the problem, but module poms already have spring-boot-starter-parent declared as their parent.

### Questions

- Is it possible to use properties from aggregator pom without making it a parent?
- How can I separate integration tests from unit tests by using properties in aggregator pom?

**ps.** I assure you that I adhere to naming conventions: unit tests are named like `*Test.java` and integration tests are named like `*IT.java`. So maven-failsafe-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make your aggregator as a parent for your modules, and than configure aggregator to have `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent this problem will be solved.(assuming your aggregator does not have any parent currently).

Or you can pass skip test property from command line like `-Dskip.unit.tests=true`(where you call your mvn clean verify).

As a side note, when you execute `mvn test` command you don't have to specify integration test to skip, because it is later in the lifecycle.(it won't be executed any way)

Comment: I can not make the aggregator as parent. Thank you for directions!